# I have a *.domain.com cert and would like to use it as my root CA cert

Tags: windows-server-2008, certificate, certificate-authority

I have a *.domain.com cert and would like to use it as my root CA cert. Just for clarification. I just brought a wildcard certificate. I was wondering if I could pull it into my Domain Controller CA and have it issue all the certificate across my domain? Computer or Web or Server certificates.

Comment: What are the BasicConstraints on your certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not posible, you can only use this one certificate for all your services on third level domain under domain.com. Wildcard certificate don't give you ability generate subsequent certificates.

If you want generate your own certificates, need own CA. This CA must be installed on all host, which need trust issued certificates

Comment: +1 Check the 'Key usage' field on the wildcart certificate. It will almost certainly report 'Digital Signature, Key Encipherment'. A CA signing cert will report 'Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing' or similar.